# tomcat session replication with osgi

Tags: java, session, tomcat, osgi, cluster-computing

I have configured tomcat cluster for master slave:

```
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" appName="virgo-kernel"
                        userClassNames="org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.authentication.User"
                        roleClassNames="org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.authentication.Role"/>

                <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
                        unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false"
                        deployOnStartup="false" createDirs="false">

                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="serviceability/logs/access"
                        prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>

                    <Valve className="org.eclipse.virgo.web.tomcat.support.ApplicationNameTrackingValve"/>
                </Host>


                <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
                             channelSendOptions="8">

                      <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
                               expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                               notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

                      <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
                        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                                    address="228.0.0.4"
                                    port="45564"
                                    frequency="500"
                                    dropTime="3000"
                                    bind="192.168.3.33"/>
                        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                                  address="192.168.3.33"
                                  port="4000"
                                  autoBind="100"
                                  selectorTimeout="5000"
                                  maxThreads="6"/>

                        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
                          <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
                        </Sender>
                        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
                        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
                      </Channel>

                      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
                             filter=""/>
                      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>

                      <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                                tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                                deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                                watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                                watchEnabled="false"/>

                      <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
                      <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
                  </Cluster>
            </Engine>
```

And I've used the "netsh interface ip show joins" command to show that my network card already has multicast.

My architecture :

```
    DNS server1 --------------------------DNS server2
        |                                    |
    Nginx1(proxy_pass to master ip1)        Nginx2(proxy_pass to master ip1)
        |                                     |
    Virgo1(tomcat)                        Virgo2(tomcat)
```

And I have a component can always modify the nginx configuration file so that it always points to the host ip, and then reload nginx.
But I have a problem now: it copies the session, but it does not copy it when the session changes.
Server A's(master) session's attributeNames: a b c d(Sort by time)
Server B's(slave) session's attributeNames:a b
And i didn't use NTP service and server A's time is different with Server B's time.

Comment: I have debugged SimpleTcpCluster ,master invoked  send() method, slave invoke messageReceived() method,this is not representative for a session copy?

Comment: Is not NTP service cause of this problem?

Comment: And i have added <distributable/> in web.xml

Comment: "server A's time is different with Server B's time" - change that before looking for problems higher up in the stack. I fail to see what this has to do with OSGi

Comment: I found out the reason: I use osgi,and its classLoader can not find the class.I must modify tomcat get class's way